# what is the equivalent JAVA Spring Boot code of Mongo DB query

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework, mongotemplate

I have written MongoDB Query for display last one week users count, based
lastActive field from Profile collection, lastActive field is date string.
Can someone please help me to write corresponding Spring Boot java code of
this using SimpleDateFormat class or LocalDate class. Please

```
var today = new Date();
var lastWeekStart = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - 7);
var lastWeekEnd = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - 7);
var start = new Date(lastWeekStart.setHours(0,0,0,0));
var end = new Date(lastWeekEnd.setHours(23,59,59,999));

db.Profile.aggregate([
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "total": { "$sum": 1 },
        "LastWeekUsersList": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [
                    { 
                        "$and": [
                            { "$gte": [ "$lastActive", start ] },
                            { "$lte": [ "$lastActive", end ] }
                        ]
                    },
                    1,
                    0
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
])
```

How to write corresponding spring boot code of this, I am not sure how to write the java equivalent query of mongo db, please help me someone

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this (not tested)

```
    @Autowired
    private MongoOperations mongoOperations;

    public MongoOperations getMongoOperations() {
        return mongoOperations;
    }
```

```
   .... 
    Instant start = Instant.parse("2020-07-13T10:30:00.000Z");
    Instant end = Instant.parse("2020-07-20T10:37:00.000Z");
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria().andOperator(
        Criteria.where("lastActive").gt(start),
        Criteria.where("lastActive").lt(end)
    );
    ConditionalOperators.Cond sumCond = ConditionalOperators.when(criteria).then(true).otherwise(false);
    GroupOperation groupOperation = Aggregation.group().count().as("total").sum(sumCond).as("LastWeekUsersList");
    List<MappedType> mappeRes = getMongoOperations().aggregate(Aggregation.newAggregation(
        groupOperation
    ), "myCollecgtion", MappedType.class).getMappedResults();
```

Comment: No its not working , what is group() method it is showing error

Comment: org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.group()

Comment: It is showing getMongoOperations() is undefined method, which class menthod that is ?

Comment: Can you please let me know